# Box2d How to create a Slider Platform

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

How to create Slider Platform in Box2d? Platform that i can move from side to side just like volume controller.

Comment: Before writing a question, you must say "what you have tried" or "what level are you at". It sounds like you know nothing about programming. What about buying some book?

Comment: i didn't try anything.. firstly before try type some code you need to have some plan how you gonna accomplished this and meanwhile i don't have any to ideas about that.. like use joints or how to use mousejoint with kinematic bodys to be able drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

```
    b2PrismaticJointDef jointDef;
    jointDef.Initialize(fixture->GetBody(), groundBody, fixture->GetBody()->GetWorldCenter(), b2Vec2(0.5f,0.0f));
    jointDef.maxMotorForce = 500.0;
    jointDef.enableMotor = true;
    jointDef.lowerTranslation = -2.5f;
    jointDef.upperTranslation =  2.5f;
    jointDef.enableLimit = true;
```